# how to plot real time updating?

Tags: python, gnuplot, using

I would like to be able to plot data 'real-time' using gnuplot Specifically, I have a file "myData.dat" which is a data file, separated by columns. The data in "myData.dat" is collected real-time from live variables I would like to have gnuplot open and plotting the data from "myData.dat" as its continuously recording data. Ideally I want the plot to show a every 1 minute. i want gnuplot for 1 hour then refresh showing the next "1 minute" of data. Right now, I have a gnuplot script "myData.dat" which reads:

[image]

In addition, how I want to save my "myData.dat" to pendrive? The data needs to logged to pendrive

Answer (score 1):

Add `pause` to your gnuplot script.

```
pause 60
reread
```

For copying your files to a pendrive you have a variety of options, a simple one from the shell would be:

`> while true; do cp mydata.dat /mnt/whatever; sleep 60; done`

Which would copy your file to your drive every minute.

You can also execute commands from within `gnuplot` if you put a `!` before the shell command.

For replotting with shell commands:

`while true; do tail -n ... |gnuplot ...; sleep 60; done`

your ADC script needs to be running of course.

Comment: i have tried the suggestion that you have propose but to no veil.

Comment: this is the program for data acquisition 

[enter image description here][2]

plotting

[enter image description here][3]

i have tried to do realtime ploting but it still needs to wait for all data to be acquired then only plot.
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gc5LS.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzfow.png

Comment: Don't mix `gnuplot` commands with normal shell commands, if you want the shell approach, see the edit.

Comment: i edited the shell command and modify the gnu command but i cannot obtains a run time data collection with plot.

Comment: [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S9xCa.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oFotj.png
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qEnts.png

Comment: Dont mix `gnuplot` and shell commands in your file. Remove the `pause 60` and `reread`.
Remove `sudo python adc_file.py` and run it from a seperate shell.